# How to refresh or set camera frame rate in Swift for iOS devices

Tags: ios, swift, camera, frame-rate

I want to allow changing the current camera frame rate 460 per minutes, which means 7.6667 frames per seconds, but the camera did not give me correct results. I tried a lot but did not achieved.

I checked the minimum and maximum frame rate of device which gave me this duration per second:

```
minFrameDuration CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 240, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)

maxFrameDuration CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 6, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0)
```

`minFrameRate 6.0`
`maxFrameRate 240.0`

I tried this block of code in my controller, but did not get the desired result:

```
 try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
                    captureDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 60, timescale: 460)
                    captureDevice.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 60, timescale: 460)
                    captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
```

Full function code is here, I am not sure if something is missing:

```
func flashlight(){
    
    let session : AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

    let videoDevices : [AVCaptureDevice] = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as! [AVCaptureDevice]
    

    for device in videoDevices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
           let captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice = device
           
           videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
           videoPreviewLayer!.frame = view.bounds
           videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity =    AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
           videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation =   AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
              view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
            
            var bestFormat: AVCaptureDevice.Format?
            var bestFrameRateRange: AVFrameRateRange?

             for format in device.formats {
                 for range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges {
                     if range.maxFrameRate > bestFrameRateRange?.maxFrameRate ?? 0 {
                         bestFormat = format
                         bestFrameRateRange = range
                     }
                 }
             }
            
            if let bestFormat = bestFormat,
                let bestFrameRateRange = bestFrameRateRange {

                do {
                    let input : AVCaptureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

                    if let port = input.ports.first(where: { $0.mediaType == .video }) {
                        let con = AVCaptureConnection(inputPort: port, videoPreviewLayer: self.videoPreviewLayer!)
                        if session.canAddConnection(con) {
                            session.addConnection(con)
                        }
                    }
                    session.addInput(input)
                    self.videoPreviewLayer!.session = session
                    session.startRunning()

                    let duration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration
                    
                    let minFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration
                    let maxFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange.maxFrameDuration
                    let minFrameRate = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameRate
                    let maxFrameRate = bestFrameRateRange.maxFrameRate

                    print("minFrameDuration \(minFrameDuration)")
                    print("maxFrameDuration \(maxFrameDuration)")
                    print("minFrameRate \(minFrameRate)")
                    print("maxFrameRate \(maxFrameRate)")

                    try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
                    captureDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 60, timescale: 460)
                    captureDevice.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 60, timescale: 460)
                    captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
                    
                    let output : AVCaptureVideoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

                    let dispatch_queue : DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(__label: "streamoutput", attr: nil)
                                output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_queue)

                    session.addOutput(output)
        
                } catch _ { }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```